# Setting path for Users/Documents folder inside .conf file

Tags: windows, redis

I have a `redis.windows.conf` file where I have to set path to the Users/Documents folder , where users will differ from system to system. I am using dir `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Documents\ABC\Redis-x64-6.2.6` to get the path but it is not working. I also tried `%USERPROFILE%` to get the path, but it didnt work. Could anyone let me know how to proceed for this for .conf file. I want to retrieve the Documents folder which should be generic and not hard coded

Comment: What is the error you get when it doesn't work?

Comment: it doesnt give any error of such. it just doesnt start. I tried hard coding the path instead of %USERPROFILE% to check if there is any permission issue, but it works in the same directory with hardcoding the path